Не работает авторизация через гугл
Есть код на node typescript
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

const CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

// Middleware для разрешения CORS запросов
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}));

// Маршрут для инициации аутентификации через Google OAuth
app.get('/auth/google', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const url = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
    });
    res.redirect(url);
});

// Маршрут обратного вызова для обработки ответа от Google OAuth
app.get('/auth/google/callback', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const code = req.query.code as string;
    try {
        const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        const userInfo = await google.oauth2({ version: 'v2', auth: oAuth2Client }).userinfo.get();
        res.send(userInfo.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при получении токена доступа', error);
        res.status(500).send('Ошибка при получении токена доступа');
    }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Сервер запущен на порте 5000');
});

Код рабочий при переходе на прямую на http://localhost:5000/auth/google, но при подключении через frontend выдаёт ошибку Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&response_type=code&client_id=789517930265-9d8g5orqgtnc2eidn7ftvqt18hanqdss.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Прикрепляю код из frontend
// reg.tsx

import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { Context } from '..'

export const Reg = () => {
    const { store } = useContext(Context)


    const handleGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            await store.googleAuth();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during Google authentication', error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleGoogle}>Google</button>
        </div>
    )
}

// store.ts
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"
import { User } from "../model/User"
import AuthService from "../service/AuthService"
import api from "../http"

export default class Store{
    user = {} as User
    error? = []
    isAuth = false
    isLoading = false
    constructor(){
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    setAuth(bool:boolean){
        this.isAuth = bool
    }
    setUser(user: User){
        this.user = user
    }
    setLoading(bool: boolean){
        this.isLoading = bool
    }

    setError(error?: []){
        this.error = error
    }


    async googleAuth(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await api.get('auth/google');
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error during Google authentication');
        }
    }   
}

//http/index.ts
import axios from 'axios';
import { AuthRespose } from '../model/AuthResponse';

export const API_URL = `http://localhost:5000/`
const api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_URL
})


не решение, а размышление - посмотреть настройки credentials google - https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials , вот там должен быть раздел OAuth 2.0 Client IDs а в нем список разрешенных доменов. Вот что-то вроде http://localhost:5000 и http://localhost:3000 там есть? Т.е. судя по документации - redirect_url - тоже там должен быть. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow?hl=ru#redirecting

Там изначально стоял localhost:3000
